# Getting rid of white space below footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap 3.0 framework and no matter what I do I cannot get the little white space after the footer to disappear.It only shows in Chrome though, in IE it's fine.

I've used `min-height, overflow:hidden,different margins` still nothing.

http://www.bootply.com/XonUL6Vq2C

I'm sure there is some simple fix that eludes me.However it is driving me mad.

Can anyone offer a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS, you are using 50px `margin` for both the top and bottom of the footer.

Remove the margin from your footer.

If you want to apply margin only on the top of the footer, use this:

```
footer {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0; /* or just use:  margin-top: 50px;*/
}
```

[UPDATED CODE](http://www.bootply.com/1c9NZ4TrFJ)

Comment: This wokerd,using margin-top and deleting margin got me the desired effect.Thanks

Comment: please mark question as completed so one can get points of it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using min-height and padding bottom in `#cfoot.container`. Remove that and you'll get as you expect.

[working demo](http://www.bootply.com/SIRkZ6KfkH)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a negative margin-bottom until the white space is filled.
E.g

```
footer { margin: 0 0 -50px 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes also happens when you forget adding a closing tag of a section.